# What is the time complexity of Java StringBuilder.substring() method? If it is linear, is there a constant time complexity method to get a substring?

Tags: java, string, substring, time-complexity, stringbuilder

In my opinion it should be constant(O(1)) time complexity. However I was told that a new String object has to be instantiated when invoking stringBuilder.substring() method. (It is not static method). If this is true, how can I get a substring within a constant time complexity?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot possibly create a `String` from a `StringBuilder` in constant time and have its immutability maintained. Additionally, as of Java 7 Update 25, even `String#substring()` is linear time because structural sharing actually caused more trouble than it avoided: substring of a huge string retained a reference to the huge `char` array.

Answer (score 2):

> In my opinion it should be constant(O(1)) time complexity.

This is not possible. Since Java strings are immutable, while `StringBuilder`s are mutable, all operations that produce a `String` must make a copy.

> If this is true, how can I get a substring within a constant time complexity?

You cannot. Without a copy, changing characters inside a substring would mutate the `String`, which is not allowed.

Comment: In principle, why wouldn't it be possible to have `StringBuilder.substring()` return a subclass of `String` which, instead of being backed by a `char[]`, is backed by the parent `String` and an offset to tell it where to start/end? No copying required.

Comment: @AdrianPetrescu Because there is no parent `String`. There is a parent `StringBuilder`, which is mutable.

Comment: Plus, `String` is `final` for important security reasons. When you receive a `String` from a caller, you want to be positively sure its immutability is a guaranteed property.

Answer (score 0):

StringBuilder's substring actually copies the characters from start index to end index, so it tries to array copy of characters of substring length(i.e end index-startindex). This will be the time complexity of this operation O(substringlength) as the loop runs from start index to end index which cannot be avoided. With this the substring char[], string object will be instantiated.